# functions returning pointers

Tags: c

I came across a program in c:

```
int bags[5]={20,5,20,3,20};
int main()
{
    int pos=5,*next();
    *next()=pos;   //problem with this line(should give error :lvalue required)
    printf("%d %d %d",pos,*next(),bags[0]);
    return 0; 
}
int *next()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        if(bags[i]==20)
            return (bags+i); 
    printf("error");
    exit(0);
}
```

> the output to the program is 5 20 5 though i expected it to be lvalue required.
>       can anyone tell the reason???

Comment: Doesn't compile in codepad (http://codepad.org/98m9rEjj). The problematic line indeed gives an error. What compiler did you use?

Comment: @ugoren remove two `*` from each sid eof the sentence, this is a formmating issue.

Comment: This code isn't legal C code. Lines 4 and 5 seem to have syntax errors.

Comment: @ssteinberg - line four is a valid function declaration, line 5 - see my previous comment.

Comment: this code is No problem. *(int pointer) = 5; //normal syntax

Answer (score 2):

While `next()` is not lvalue, `*next()` is, this is an int, addressed by the return value if *next()`(which is an int in the`bags` array).

In other words, while you can't assign to the return value of a function, you can assign to the value which is addressed by the return value.

Comment: ,@ugoren -how can *next() be an lvalue?? *next() is a function call which returns the address(a constant)..and how can a constant be an lvalue

Comment: *next() will not be an int. it will be an address pointing towards a integer value.

Comment: Not exactly, *next() is an int variable pointed by the return value of next.

Answer (score 2):

`next()` is not an lvalue, because function return values are not.
`*next()` is an lvalue, because its a value contained at some known memory address. Whether this address was obtained as a function's return value or otherwise (e.g. it was stored in a variable), doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the dereference operator `*` *is* an lvalue.

"The unary * operator denotes indirection. [...] if it points to an object, the result is an lvalue designating the object." C99 6.5.3.2/4